# Does it make sense to use "only" to modify the bigger number and use "significant" to modify the smaller one?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I think, usually, "only" is used to modify smaller numbers. In this context, does it make sense to use **only** to modify the bigger number and use **significant** to modify the smaller number? Is this logical?

> **Only** 35% of female members were very satisfied with the opening hours, while a **significant** 30% expressed dissatisfaction.

I wrote the sentence. The context is 35% of women were very satisfied, another 35% were satisfied and the remaining 30% were not satisfied.

Comment: Those two sentences **mean different things**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit

The earlier example using "opening hours" to discuss customer satisfaction may not be suitable.  I give another one.

Let's say two people are discussing about the chances of a certain politician winning.  **A** argues that the chances are not high:

> **Only** 35% of the population were very satisfied with this politician while a **significant** 30% expressed dissatisfaction.

**B** believes that the chances are quite high and may use the opposite:

> **A significant** 35% of the population were very satisfied ... while **only** 30% expressed dissatisfaction.

Earlier Answer:

> **Only** 35% of female members were very satisfied ... while a **significant** 30% expressed dissatisfaction.

The choice of adjectives depends on what the speaker wants to focus on. Let's say a group of users is expressing its dissatisfaction over the opening hours of certain premises, the above structure could be its statement.  The operator of the premises would use the opposite:

> **A significant** 35% of female members were very satisfied ... while **only** 30% expressed dissatisfaction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think no matter what product or service is under discussion, 30% of customers being dissatisfied means there are a lot of dissatisfied customers, not "only". How can any company survive with around a third of customers being dissatisfied?

Comment: You're quite right.  I've just edited my answer.